# Is its ok to have multiple implementations per target in XCode?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have a header file that defines a class interface:

```
// MyClass.h - included in all targets
//
@interface MyClass
+ (void) doThing;
@end
```

And I have two different implementation files - one per target.

```
// MyClass+targetA.m - Only included in targetA
//
@implementation MyClass
+ (void) doThing { NSLog(@"targetA"); }
@end


// MyClass+targetB.m - Only included in targetB
//
@implementation MyClass
+ (void) doThing { NSLog(@"targetB"); }
@end
```

- Are there any issues with this approach?
- Is there a better or simpler way to customise behaviour of each target?

*The method MyClass will be for themeing the appearance of an app.  There will be several methods on MyClass and several targets*

Comment: Are these two implementations so wildly different that they're justified being in different source files? If not, #ifdef based on a target-specific preprocessor definition might be a better choice. If you decide to keep two files though, I suggest changing their name. I've seen Xcode get confused when two files have the same name (building fine, but presenting the wrong one in the editor sometimes).

Comment: @mah - Interesting! Thanks for your response.  I had though of using preprocessor defines because I had used them in the past as well.  The implementation is for themeing an app for different clients, so there is quite a bit of variety between implementations.  Great tip about change the names - I hadn't though that would be possible.

Comment: There's no connection between the class name and the source file name, so definitely possible -- but best to name them in a way that makes sense of course… such as MyClass_client1.m, MyClass_client2.m, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that will work fine, and I have taken a similar approach, except that I have used conditional compilation, with one target exposing private functionality and another target exposing public functionality, but all targets sharing the same set of source files.

However the results of both our approaches are the same.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I don't quite understand what you mean by "target exposing private functionality and another target exposing public functionality". It sounds interesting tho, could you explain it a little?

Comment: @Robert It's simply that I want to provide a static library to the public with limited functionality, so I use a constant during compilation to control what goes into the private and public builds.

Answer (score 1):

So I'm actually prefer to setup `OTHER_CFLAGS` in target settings with my custom flag like `TARGET_FREE` for one of them. And then in the source I can write something like:

```
@implementation MyClass
+ (void) doThing {

#ifdef TARGET_FREE 
    // Code for one target
#else
    // Code for another
#endif

}
@end
```

Comment: Yes I had used this in the past and it works nicely.  The issue is the complexity of `MyClass`. It has about 20 methods on it (Its for Themeing a template app for different clients).  I would see the code getting more complicated as the number of targets and methods grows if implemented this way.

Comment: OK. I see. So at lest it will compile and work as it should. May be you could encounter some navigation or code sense problems in xcode when editing related code but not sure.

Comment: Yes confirmed the shortcut navigation from header to source is broken.  I took the advice of trojanfoe and renamed each .m file.  I think I can live with that tho

Comment: Why do you use the `OTHER_CFLAGS` when your constant can go into the normal macro section of the build settings?